# AWK syntax problem

Tags: awk

I want to subtract a column from 100 using awk. I have tried

```
awk '{ t = 100-$2 } END { print t }' /alps/average.log
```

It gave me only the last value subtracted. How it can be accomplished if I want the whole column outputted on terminal?

Comment: @mouviciel: "substract" is not a word.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
awk '{print 100-$2}' /alps/average.log
```

Commands after the `END` label are executed only after end of file.

Answer (score 0):

`print t` in an unlabeled block, definitely not in one labeled `END`!